# Maclaurin series and general terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

For a general term in a maclaurin (or any other) series e.g. x^r/r! is it always that r=0, or r=1 at the first term or does it have nothing to do with the term it appears in e.g. r=10 could come before the term when r=9, I ask because my formula book changes from r=0 for the first to r=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the function. The r=0 term may have a zero coefficient, in which case, you can skip it. Some functions may have many zero terms before the series actually starts.

The *order* of terms is usually given in increasing powers of $x$. You may exchange some terms at the beginning of the series, but how would you write it in a practical $\sum$ notation? And why would you mess with the order?

Note that while permuting some early terms (like exchanging r=9 and r=10) has no effect, you shouldn't reorder them in a way that messes with the order all the way to infinity - this can make the series divergent, or worse, make it converge to the wrong value (conditional convergence).